# Code interpreter and runner for Java and Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, interpreter

**Problem:**

We are looking for a way to interpret and execute source code at runtime. I would like suggestions.

We are developing a game where the user must write source code to complete the challenges, like the [CodinGame](https://www.codingame.com/).

The game objective is to help students who are starting in programming disciplines.

Requirements:

- The game is developed with [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) (for Java Desktop and Android)
- The student will have a limited set of methods that can be invoked, like `turnLeft()`, `turnRight()`, `go()`, and others.
- It should be possible to use statements such as `IF/ELSE`, `FOR` and `WHILE`.
- It will be very good if you can show errors in the code written by the student.

So we began to look for ways of implementation.

At first we thought of using "Aspect Oriented Programming", but did not find anything that can dynamically read the source code of the students.

Compilers as InstantJ are not an option because it uses JAVAC, making it impossible to build within the Android.

So we thought of something to read the source code entered by the user and "running in memory," calling the methods via reflection. Or something like that.

It has also been suggested something like LISP or LOGO interpreters, but the problem in this case is the syntax. We would like students to learn a language that can be used in the future.

The solution we are looking at now is [JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser). But this library literally makes the code parser and does not interpret the instructions. Here we have to execute calls via reflection manually. And it is difficult to interpret conditions such as IF, FOR, etc.

**Question:**

Our goal is that the user can write Java (or JavaScript) code that should make calls to predefined methods. The methods are already implemented in the game classes. We are not looking for a library specifically, we would like suggestions for research.

Any suggestions for something that we can look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching and talking to friends, I believe I got a very nice solution!

During the search I found the [Rhino](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino) library, and with it I can make script using JavaScript without requiring compilation.

```
private void executeScript() {
    String source = "" +
            "game.walk();\n" +
            "game.walk();\n" +
            "var jumps = 10;\n" +
            "for (var i = 0; i < jumps; i++) {\n" +
            "   game.jump(i + 1);\n" +
            "}";


    org.mozilla.javascript.Context cx = org.mozilla.javascript.Context.enter();
    cx.setOptimizationLevel(-1); // disable compilation
    Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();
    Object wrappedOut = cx.javaToJS(this, scope);
    ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "game", wrappedOut);
    Object result = cx.evaluateString(scope, source, "<cmd>", 1, null);

}

public void walk() {
    System.out.println("Walking!");
}

public void jump(int count) {
    System.out.println("Jumping! " + count);
}
```

Output:

```
System.out: Walking!
System.out: Walking!
System.out: Jumping! 1
System.out: Jumping! 2
System.out: Jumping! 3
System.out: Jumping! 4
System.out: Jumping! 5
System.out: Jumping! 6
System.out: Jumping! 7
System.out: Jumping! 8
System.out: Jumping! 9
System.out: Jumping! 10
```

Perfect!